# WPF DataGrid large dataset selection performance

Tags: wpf, datagrid, selection

Any clue how to solve WPF DataGrid performance for selecting large amount of rows with extended selection mode/ Full Row? (hundreds of thousands of rows)

For load time I have solved with Virtualization and Lists, but now if the user select all the rows  the UI blocks...

I tried to find previous questions on this but no luck.

Thanks of any assiatance

Comment: My suggestion would be not to do it. Why would a user want to interact with hundreds of thousands of rows in a datagrid?  You've arrived at an impractical design somehow. Do whatever you aim to achieve some other way.

Comment: First, offer a search and filtering. This way you can significantly reduce the size of the displayed data set. You also reduce the database query result, the memory consumption and the startup time. Because you now can use your database for search and filtering your application becomes faster. Maybe most important, you are more likely to display data that the user is interested in. Then use data virtualization, for example by reading and displaying data in pages. Like an Amazon product page where you can scroll through like 20 items before you have to load the next page.

Comment: Then to select items you use check boxes that hold their state by storing it in the item. This allows convenient multi-selections across multiple data pages.

Comment: Just take a look at how big internet shops or sport statistic websites handle their huge amount of data. Usually instead of an endless and tiny scrollbar you get pages, which is essential for implementing data virtualization.

Comment: thanks for your remarks! I'll follow your clues!